# SVG Compass Rose

Tags: svg

I'm assisting a colleague with a coding project. I'm no coder so he's doing all the clever stuff and I'm building the visual assets as SVG's. I've done little bits of coding in the past so I'm

One of the assets I need to make is a compass rose. It needs every 10 degree point to have a large tick, and every five-degree point in between those to have a shorter tick. (i.e., 36 large ticks interspersed with 36 smaller ticks at equidistant points around an invisible circle)

I found this snippet courtesy of another user's question which is ideal, but I can't work out how to modify the ticks to the correct number of ticks and the two differing sizes:

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="500px" height="500px" viewBox="0 0 165 165" enable-background="new 0 0 165 165" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
    
  <circle fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="9" stroke-miterlimit="23" stroke-dasharray="1.0048,6.0288" cx="82.453" cy="82.563" r="75"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Any advice to modify, or a completely different approach would be gratefully received! I've build all the polygons myself, but this is a bit of a mind twister...

Comment: You will need to calculate the stroke-dasharray value yourself. Keep in mind that the perimeter of the circle in this case is 2*Math.PI * 75.  In the example above probably you have 67 divissions. If you need 36 (every 10 degs) you do  2*Math.PI * 75/36 = 13.0899. If you decide the width of each tic to be 1 stroke-dasharray = "1, 12.0899"

Comment: Won't a ``pathLength="36"`` _attribute_ do?